# Same data is getting saved two times when react app loads

Tags: reactjs

When I load my react app, the same data gets copied two times in a useState hook. I am making a call to the API inside the useEffect hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const data = await getProducts(limit);
      setProducts((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...data.products]);
    };

    try {
      fetchProducts();
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [limit]);
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-shopping-cart-with-products-efbw3c?file=/src/hooks/useInfiniteScroll.js:266-629

Comment: It's triggering twice because of `Strict.Mode` if you remove it it will be solved

Comment: do you edit limit value in other lines your code? can you share all of the codes will help more to understand your issue

Comment: @FurkanGökmen codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-shopping-cart-with-products-efbw3c?file=/src/hooks/useInfiniteScroll.js:266-629